# Create trigger for view to edit table's data

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, triggers

I would like to ask what is wrong with my trigger for view.
View:

```
CREATE VIEW PRODUKT_VIEW  AS SELECT * FROM PRODUKT;
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger dawka_zeruj
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON PRODUKT_VIEW
DECLARE
begin
    if(:old.dawka = :new.dawka)
    then
    update produkt_view set dawka_l_p = null, dawka_j_p = null where bloz12=:old.bloz12;
    end if;
END;
```

After executing it sql developer asks for paramters.. I tought that :old, :new are paramters from update but it seems like it is not.. What I do wrong?

PS. I want to set 2 columns: "dawka_l_p" and "dawka_j_p" to null if someone will change column "dawka" on update. Thats all. Bloz12 is PRIMARY KEY.

PS2. dawka is varchar2 column so probably it should be if(:old.dawka like :new.dawka) but still it does not work.

Definition of table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUKT 
(
  BLOZ7 NUMBER 
, BLOZ12 NUMBER 
, NAZWA VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, NAZWA_MIEDZ VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, DAWKA VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) 
, DAWKA_ZLOZ VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
, DAWKA_L_P FLOAT(126) 
, DAWKA_J_P VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, DAWKA_L_R FLOAT(126) 
, DAWKA_J_R VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, DAWKA_L_N FLOAT(126) 
, DAWKA_J_N VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, POSTAC VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) 
, OPAKOWANIE VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) 
, PODMIOT_ODP VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, PODMIOT_ODP_KRAJ VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) 
, NAZWA_PELNA VARCHAR2(310 BYTE) 
, OPAK_NAJM_ZAREJ VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) 
, TEMP_OD FLOAT(126) 
, TEMP_DO FLOAT(126) 
, CENY_ID NUMBER 
, WYTWORCA_ID NUMBER 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE "USERS" 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
);

ALTER TABLE PRODUKT
ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUKT_CENY_URZEDOWE FOREIGN KEY
(
  CENY_ID 
)
REFERENCES CENY_URZEDOWE
(
  ID 
)
ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE PRODUKT
ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUKT_WYTWORCA FOREIGN KEY
(
  WYTWORCA_ID 
)
REFERENCES WYTWORCA
(
  ID 
)
ENABLE;
```

Comment: In the trigger, is it intended that you update the view once again: `update produkt_view set dawka_l_p =...`. Should it not have been: `update produkt set dawka_l_p = ...` ?

Comment: Ok, I found another thing: I should "run it as script" not as "statement" (from sql developer). I have changed produkt_view to produkt but it still does not work..

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `produkt` table?

Comment: I get no errors or prompts from that, in SQL Developer, and it comiles fine [as a SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de1a3/1).

Comment: Ok, I got a almost final trigger:
create or replace trigger dawka_zeruj
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON PRODUKT_VIEW
DECLARE
begin
    if(:old.dawka not like :new.dawka)
    then
    update produkt set dawka_l_p = null, dawka_j_p = null, dawka=:new.dawka where bloz12=:old.bloz12;
    end if;
END;

Problem is that if i want to update any other field like 'nazwa' (name) update does not work because it has not any else in this trigger.. Is it anything like do update as normal after else?

Comment: In other words: 
if(:old.dawka not like :new.dawka) do MY_UPDATE
else do NORMAL_UPDATE AS USER SPECIFIED
I just miss any oracle words to do user specified update.

Comment: You have to specify the full update statement for both branches. Simplest way here might be to change your `:new` value in the `if`, and then update the real table using all the `:new` values. Or you could have a record type that you set from the `:new` values, change in the `if`, and then use for the real update. You want `!=` rather than `not like` though. Not sure why you want the trigger on the view instead of the table in this case though.

Comment: Great, It solves my question. It's just for studies example (it is must for view) :) Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you must specify the full update statement for both cases.

```
create or replace trigger dawka_zeruj
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON PRODUKT_VIEW    
DECLARE 
begin 
  if(:old.dawka <> :new.dawka) then 
     -- change the :new values, to re-use
     :new.dawka_l_p = null;
     :new.dawka_j_p = null;
  end if; 
  -- then the update can be done in any cases to your table.
  update produkt 
     set dawka_l_p = :new.dawka_l_p
       , dawka_j_p = :new.dawka_j_p
       , dawka     = :new.dawka 
   where bloz12=:old.bloz12; 
END;
```